# How to transform a path in svg so that it is parallel to its original location?

Tags: svg, translation, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I have a path defined in SVG. I would like to make two copies of the path and translate them so that one sits parallel to the original on one side, and the other sits parallel on the other side. The idea is to end up with 3 paths, all parallel to each other and not overlapping.

I have tried simple translations such as transform="translate(10,10)" and transform="translate(-10,-10)" for the two paths, but in some paths they end up crossing each other which is not what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you point us to the SVG file, so one can take a look at your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer should somewhat work as you've provided it. You might provide more concrete examples of your problem to evoke better solutions.

Your provided commands are going to move the item in two dimensions, not just one.

Also, keep in mind that SVG uses the upper left point as 0,0, and to the right/down are positive. Also check to make sure you're not getting tripped up by units.

Answer (score 0):

If your original path has a bounding box of X,Y then the simplest way to make sure that the copied don't overlap is to translate by +X and -X, so:

```
translate(-X, 0)
```

and

```
translate(X, 0)
```

where you have computed the value of X and set it in the translate argument.

Comment: I can see what you are trying, however with this solution the two lines will be parallel only if the original is vertical. If the original line is horizontal, you will have 3 lines drawn on top of each other.

Comment: You use both "path" and "lines" in your description. I think it would help if you described your requirements more precisely.
ANY line when cloned and translated will result in parallel lines, regardless of the angle. Similarly the lines of a path will always have a parallel equivalent in the cloned path.
The degenerate case (with a single vertical or horizontal line) should be trapped. But if you add a small padding box (P = 10, say) to your bounding box then the commands translate(X+P, 0) and translate (-X-P, 0) [X is width of bounding box] can never overlap

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some completely untested code written without looking at the SVG DOM spec.  You can then test it and tweak it to get it to work.

First, get the bounding box of an element:

`var box = mypath.getBBox();`

Then clone the path twice (or make  elements):

`var rightCopy = mypath.cloneNode(true);
var bottomCopy = mypath.cloneNode(true);`

Then transform each copy:

`rightCopy.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + box.width + ",0) " + rightCopy.getAttribute("transform"));`

`bottomCopy.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0," + box.height + ") " + bottomCopy.getAttribute("transform"));`

The reason it looks messy is because the original path might have a transform already on it.

Then add those nodes back into the DOM:

`mypath.parentNode.insertBefore(rightCopy, mypath);`

`mypath.parentNode.insertBefore(bottomCopy, mypath);`